# Saving JWT in the client side

Tags: node.js, authorization, passport.js

I'm using PassportJS to implement a JWT authorization strategy in a NodeJS/Express app.

In all tutorials, the JWT token is just sent back by the POST /login route and is manually inserted into the request's headers for demonstration (see [Learn using JWT with Passport authentication](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/learn-using-jwt-with-passport-authentication-9761539c4314), [Learn how to handle authentication with Node using Passport.js](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-how-to-handle-authentication-with-node-using-passport-js-4a56ed18e81e)), which works fine in the context of an API, but not of a web app accessible from a browser.

My question is: how do you save the authorization token in the client side so that the browser sends it every time in its requests' headers?

Here is an overview of my code (I removed the non-essential lines):

**#users.js**

```
router.post('/login', auth.optional, (req, res, next) => {

  return passport.authenticate('local', { session: false }, (err, passportUser, info) => {
    if (err) {
      res.render('/users/login');
    }

    if (passportUser) {
      const user = passportUser;
      user.token = passportUser.generateJWT();

      return res.json({ user: user.toAuthJSON() });
      // I want to set the auth header here
    }

    return res.status(400).info;
  })(req, res, next);
});

router.get('/me', auth.required, (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('me'); // Throws a 401 - No authorization token was found
});
```

Trying to access /me throws a **401 - No authorization token was found** error, which makes sense since the token is never set. But how to implement this?

**#middleware/auth.js**

```
const getTokenFromHeaders = (req) => {
  ...
};

const auth = {
  required: jwt({
    secret: 'secret',
    userProperty: 'payload',
    getToken: getTokenFromHeaders
  }),
  optional: jwt({
    secret: 'secret',
    userProperty: 'payload',
    getToken: getTokenFromHeaders,
    credentialsRequired: false
  })
};
```

**config/passport.js**

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password'
}, (email, password, done) => {
  User.findOne({ email })
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user || !user.validatePassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { errors: { 'email or password': 'is invalid' } });
      }

      return done(null, user);
    }).catch(err => done(err));
}));
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Have your backend set it as a `HttpOnly` and `Secure` cookie on the same domain or a subdomain that your front end resides on.  Then in your frontend, you need to set `credentials: include` on all of your requests back to your server, which indicates that your front end should include any cookies it received from the server in all requests back to the server. Setting JWT in a cookie is the preferred way to store access tokens and is the best option to protect against malicious attacks as the cookie cannot be read by any javascript injected on your site. See source below.

Or, if you don't have ability to set the JWT in a cookie on your server for whatever reason, maybe you don't control it or you are using a third party auth provider like Microsoft Active Directory as your token issuer. In that case, you can go the much less ideal route and set the JWT in local storage, which is highly susceptible to being stolen since any javascript running on your site has access to local storage.

Source: https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage